# Call Custom Code Upon Item Deletion in Sitecore

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

Is there a way to call custom code when an item is deleted within Sitecore? Or can I somehow attach code to a publish action?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can subscribe to `item:deleted` event. Check this article: [Using events](http://sdn.sitecore.net/Articles/API/Using%20Events.aspx).

Attaching to `item:deleted` will work only if you have a single server solution. If you have separated the content delivery and the content edit servers then it will be a bit more involved.

Comment: Wouldn't item:deleted get called on the delivery server / web database when the publishing job deletes the item? EDIT: Oops, just realized, you're right. It wouldn't. You'd need to tie into the cache clearing that executes after a publish is finished.

Comment: For content deliver servers you need to either poll the history table for 6.0 - 6.2 or subscribe to the event queue if using 6.3+